# Angular 2 syntax for binding 2 objects to 1 event

Tags: angular, angular-template

I want to bind 2 simple input fields to 1 click event in Angular. One box shall be a normal input to type in text, the other one will provide a timestamp as `Date();`.
How do I display both values with the click event on the button?

```
// input #date offers the timestamp timestamp

<input #date type="text" placeholder="now">
<input #text type="text">
<p><b>{{now}}</b> {{values}}</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="values=box.value | text.value">Log Data</button>
```

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do, can you add any example, it seems that you want  {{date.value  + text.value}}

Comment: yes. that's what i want. current date & time by `Date(); ` as `date` from the component.ts and as `text` whatever is value of the input. both should be displayed in <p>{{values}}</p> after the button is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to guess as to your intent but if you are trying to capture both inputs why not use direct model binding (requires the FormsModule to be imported)?

HTML:

```
<input #date type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" [(ngModel)]="dateToLog">
<input #text [(ngModel)]="textToLog" type="text">
<div *ngIf="logValues">
<p *ngFor="let val of logValues"><b>{{val | json}}</b></p>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="logValue()">Log Data</button>
```

TypeScript:

```
logValues: any = [];
dateToLog: string = "";
textToLog: string = "";

logValue(): void {
   let d = new Date(Date.parse(this.dateToLog));

   let len = this.logValues.length;

   let name1 = ("date_" + len);
   let name2 = ("text_" + len);

   let x = { };
   x[name1] = d;
   x[name2] = this.textToLog;
   this.logValues.push(x);
   this.dateToLog = "";
   this.textToLog = "";
}
```